# How to "impose" texture while sculpting?

Tags: sculpting

I want to sculpt like here, 5:16:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gs5nBoIxnOg&t=316 The Rock Essentials

And also question - can I use this method also in texturing, not only in sculpting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I understanded how to do this.

Open your texture for brush, in Texture > Mapping set "Area Plane", in Stroke > Stroke method set "Anchorched", like on picture. May be in Texture settings in Extension you should set "Crop", but may be it is not changes. Also, all pictures will be compressed to square, remember it (may be there is a method to keep size, but I dont know).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To sculpt with a texture, go into sculpt mode, select the draw brush, and add a texture by clicking the `New` button as shown below:

[image: a]

Then go into the texture panel, and select an image for your texture with the open button:

[image: open]

Then, to be able to draw the texture in place while controlling the size as in the video, you need to set the stroke mode to `Anchored` in the brush settings:
[image: stroke]

Now just ensure your mesh has enough geometry (or use dyntopo with a high level of detail), and you can sculpt a texture onto your mesh.

Comment: It is not that I need. On the video is other method, he is like "glue" texture on a mesh

Comment: If you want something different, you'll need to link a different timestamp in the video then.

Comment: @person312 so I link true time, 5:16. Your method does not mathes. Someone among us mistaking